# 現在のLinkedInでのAPI経由のjob_searchの方法

Tags: webapi

api経由でjob_searchを行いたいのですが、ユーザー認証を行ってaccesstokenを取得したうえで

```
./v2/job-search
```

などを叩いてみているのですが、404となり取得できていない状況です。

※下記のレスポンスになっています。

```
{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Resource job-search does not exist","status":404}
```

またscopeも何をリクエストすればよいのかわからない状態です。

アプリケーション認証が必要ではないのか？と考えてはいるのですが、アプリケーション認証の設定もわからず、途方に暮れている所です。

現在のLinkedInでのAPI経由でのjob_searchの方法をお教えいただけませんでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

Job Search APIとしてドキュメントが見つかるのは **v1** のみです。
`https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/jobs/job-search-api`

**v2** への移行に伴い、公開APIとして利用できる機能にいくつか変更があり、すべての機能を利用するにはLinkedInとのパートナーシップの締結が必要らしい、という情報がありました。

質問本文で試された `v2/job-search` というエンドポイントはエラーが返ってきた通り存在しないので、引き続き `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/job-search` を利用するしかないのかなと思います。

**参考:**

- [LinkedIn Jobs APIs details - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43949076/2322778) (英語版での類似質問と回答)
- [Changes to our Developer Program | LinkedIn Developer Network](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) (2015/02時点での仕様変更の案内)
- [LinkedIn Triggers and Actions Being Removed - Updates | Zapier](https://zapier.com/blog/updates/439/linkedin-triggers-and-actions-being-removed) (上記の仕様変更を受けて関連する機能を削除したサードパーティツールの案内)

Comment: `./v1/job-search`

も試してみたのですが、

`{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs",
  "requestId": "T4QM33IR5A",
  "status": 410,
  "timestamp": 1569556423219
}`

こちらのエラーが返ってきており、既に使えない様です。